# How to define alternative required property in a React component PropTypes?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

This is the use case: A component `TableGroup` should require a user to specify `data` property which is an array of objects to be rendered in the table **or** `requestDataUrl` property from where the component will get that array of objects. In short, one of these two properties is required but not both. How could I achieve that in the following `component.propTypes` object?

```
TableGroup.propTypes = {
  fieldNames: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  dataFields: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  uniqueField: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  data: React.PropTypes.array,
  requestUrlSource: http://someurl/api/resource
}
```

Comment: in the mentioned propTypes, either dataFields or requestUrlSource right?

Comment: No, either `requestUrlSource` or `data`. Only one of these should be required. But not the both. @NagaSaiA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use `isRequiredIf`.

There is a [PR](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/5933) from 4 years ago by @evcohen that added `isRequiredIf` to the PropTypes library. Unfortunately, even at that time they were putting the PropTypes library in maintenance mode and would not merge it in.

The [company I work for](https://www.cntr.al/) still uses PropTypes and so we forked the `master` branch of the PropTypes library and added this functionality in.

So now you can do something like this:

```js
data:             PropTypes.array.isRequiredIf( props => !props.requestUrlSource ),
requestUrlSource: PropTypes.string.isRequiredIf( props => !props.data )
```

Super clean and minimal.

Feel free to use [our fork](https://github.com/cntral/prop-types/tree/isRequiredIf) in your own project by updating your `package.json` with the following:

```
"prop-types": "github:cntral/prop-types#isRequiredIf"
```

*NOTE: It does not take a boolean param, only a function that is passed the props and needs to return a boolean.*

Answer (score 7):

To achieve expected result, use below option

```
function dataOrRequest(props, propName, componentName) {
  return  (!props.hasOwnProperty('data') && 
             !props.hasOwnProperty('requestUrlSource')) 
            && new Error(`Either "data" or "requestUrlSource" is required`);
}


TableGroup.propTypes = {
  fieldNames: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  dataFields: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  uniqueField: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  data: dataOrRequest,
  requestUrlSource: dataOrRequest
}
```

Comment: That's great! How could you then further check for the propTypes of `data` or `requestUrlSource` in your example? let's say, you want to ensure that `data` is an object of a certain shape?

Comment: would you then just check for the PropTypes of both `data` and `requestUrlSource` as optional props?

Answer (score 3):

According to React's [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes), I think `customProp` should work perfectly for you.

```
dataOrRequest: function(props, propName, componentName) {
  function checkDataOrRequest() {
    return  (!props.hasOwnProperty('data')
      && !props.hasOwnProperty('requestUrlSource')) 
      && new Error(`Either "data" or "requestUrlSource" is required`);
  }

  function checkTypes() {
    if ((propName === 'data' && props.constructor !== Array) ||
        (propName === 'requestUrlSource' && props.constructor !== String)) {
      return new Error(
        'Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to' +
        ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
      );
    }

    return false;
  }

  return checkDataOrRequest() && checkTypes();  
}
```

after the declaration of your custom validation fn, now you could use it in

```
TableGroup.propTypes = {
  data: dataOrRequest,
  requestUrlSource: dataOrRequest
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an NPM module for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-either-property

The code maintains the type checking options, offers EitherOptional and EitherRequired strategies -- it supports combining multiple usages in one props definition.

Note: the custom rule's property name is a throwaway, and its usage as an actual property is undefined.

```
import { EitherOptional, EitherRequired } from 'react-either-property';

    [ module code goes here] 

ComponentSeven.propTypes = {
  east: PropTypes.number,
  west: PropTypes.number,
  north: PropTypes.number,
  south: PropTypes.number,
  ignored: EitherOptional('north', 'south'),
  undefined: EitherRequired('north', 'south'),
};
```